# Keras acc and val_acc is high during training but prediction is really bad

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to create a CNN which classifies images into 3 classes.
- I'm using the following versions:

- Keras 2.2.4
- Python 3.6.8
- tensorflow 1.13.1

While training my val_acc is above 90%. But when I start predict_generator
on other images (i just even used the validation images -> result is still random) the result acc for those is random.

I just printed the layers, inputs, outputs, model.summary() after loading the model and everything was fine.

I expect the output of my predictions to be better than this ...

This is my Code:

```py
import cv2
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras import optimizers
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import callbacks
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from time import gmtime, strftime

CURRENT_TIME = strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S", gmtime())
NAME = "CNN-" + CURRENT_TIME
SIZE = 280

NUM_CLASSES = 3
epochs = 25
batch_size = 64

df = pandas.read_csv("./csv/sample_tile.csv", ";")
df.columns = ['filenames', 'category']
df['category'] = df['category'].astype(str)
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

train_df, validation_df = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)

train_df = train_df.reset_index(drop=True)
validation_df = validate_df.reset_index(drop=True)


total_train = train_df.shape[0]
total_validate = validate_df.shape[0]


train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    train_df, 
    "data/", 
    x_col='filenames',
    y_col='category',
    target_size=(SIZE, SIZE),
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=batch_size,
)

# -> Found 6358 images belonging to 3 classes.

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    validation_df, 
    "data/", 
    x_col='filenames',
    y_col='category',
    target_size=(SIZE, SIZE),
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=batch_size//2,
)

# -> Found 2697 images belonging to 3 classes.

earlystop = callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=3, monitor='val_acc')

learning_rate_reduction = callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_acc', 
                                            patience=2, 
                                            verbose=1, 
                                            factor=0.5, 
                                            min_lr=0.00001)

tensorboard = callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/{}'.format(NAME))

model_checkpoint = callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath='model/checkpoint/' + NAME +'.h5',
    monitor='val_acc',
    save_best_only=True
)

callbacks = [earlystop, learning_rate_reduction, model_checkpoint, tensorboard]

def mode_architecture():
    model = Sequential()

    input_shape = (SIZE, SIZE, 3)
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), 
                     input_shape=input_shape, 
                     padding='same',
                     name='layer_conv1'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),
                           name='maxPool1'))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), 
                     padding='same', 
                     name='layer_conv2'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),
                           name='maxPool2'))

    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), 
                     padding='same', 
                     name='layer_conv3'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),
                           name='maxPool3'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128,
                    activation='relu',
                    name='fc0'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(64,
                    activation='relu',
                    name='fc1'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(32,
                    activation='relu',
                    name='fc2'))

    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.5, decay=0.0, nesterov=False)

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = mode_architecture()
model.summary()
```

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
_________________________________________________________________
layer_conv1 (Conv2D)         (None, 280, 280, 32)      896       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 280, 280, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
maxPool1 (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 140, 140, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
layer_conv2 (Conv2D)         (None, 140, 140, 64)      18496     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 140, 140, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
maxPool2 (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 70, 70, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
layer_conv3 (Conv2D)         (None, 70, 70, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 70, 70, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
maxPool3 (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 35, 35, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 156800)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc0 (Dense)                  (None, 128)               20070528  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 32)                2080      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 99        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 3)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
Total params: 20,174,211
Trainable params: 20,174,211
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

---

```py
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator, 
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=total_validate//batch_size,
    steps_per_epoch=total_train//batch_size,
    verbose=1,
    callbacks=callbacks
)
```

### Epoch 25/25 -> loss: 0.1062 - acc: 0.9610 - val_loss: 0.0721 - val_acc: 0.9780

```py
model.save("model/" + str(batch_size) + "_" + str(epochs) + "_" +  CURRENT_TIME + ".h5")

del model

model = load_model("weights/" + str(batch_size) + "_" + str(epochs) + "_" +  CURRENT_TIME + ".h5")

files_df = pandas.DataFrame(os.listdir('path/to/images/'))
files_df.columns = ['filenames']

#shuffle
files_df = files_df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
files_df = files_df.reset_index(drop=True)

files_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)
files_generator = files_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
            files_df, 
            path_to_image_slices, 
            x_col='filenames',
            target_size=(SIZE, SIZE),
            class_mode=None,
            batch_size=64,
            )
predictions = model.predict_generator(files_generator,
                                      steps=value//batch_size,
                                      verbose=1)
```

**EDIT:**

train_df_plot:

[image: img]

```
train_df['category'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

validation_df plot:

[image: img]

```
validation_df['category'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYdgM.png)

```
df = pandas.read_csv("./csv/sample_tile.csv", ";")
```

#### That is the way how I plot the result

```py
# select the index with the maximum probability
test_list_df = pandas.DataFrame(prediction_test)
test_list_df.columns = ['class1', 'class2', 'class3']
test_list = test_list_df.values.tolist()
max_value_idx = test_list_df.idxmax(axis=1)

test_filenames = test_generator.filenames
results=pandas.DataFrame({"Filenames":test_filenames,
                      "Predictions":max_value_idx})
length = len(test_list)/2
length = int(length)

# settings
nrows, ncols = 4, 2  # array of sub-plots
figsize = [25, 25]     # figure size, inches

# create figure (fig), and array of axes (ax)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=figsize)

# plot simple raster image on each sub-plot
for i, axi in enumerate(ax.flat):
    # i runs from 0 to (nrows*ncols-1)
    # axi is equivalent with ax[rowid][colid]
    img = cv2.imread('data/' + results.iloc[i]['Filenames'])
    #img_s = cv2.resize(img, (SIZE,SIZE))
    axi.imshow(img)
    # get indices of row/column
    rowid = i // ncols
    colid = i % ncols
    # write row/col indices as axes' title for identification
    axi.set_title("Row:"+str(rowid)+", Col:"+str(colid) + results.iloc[i]['Predictions'], size=20)

plt.tight_layout(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about class labels? Are they in equal proportion? Also note that `math.log(3)` is approximately `0.109` and your training loss is `0.1062` as well, that is fairly close; it could be the case that your model is only predicting one class which is abundant in your training set.

Comment: Hello @Vitrioil i edited my post. Do u need more information? btw thank you for ur help

Comment: It seems that all three are the same images..

Comment: oh yes sorry. I fixed it

Comment: I am so sorry, `math.log(3)` is `1.09` not `0.109` and there doesn't seem to be a class imbalance problem. Let me see.

Comment: When you say the result is random, it seems that it could be an [indexing issue](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/37259/keras-prediction-performance-does-not-match-accuracy).

Comment: @vitrioil I don't think that i messed up the index (but I m not sure) I just added the way of plotting the result in my post.